# Supabase 401 error while getting user's data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, supabase

I have a homes table with the columns like id, title, images, price ..., user_id. I've tried to get the user's email and full_name properties. Whenever I try to get the user's data I get 401 error with the response message "Users not allowed".

I've been building my React app with Supabase.
Here's my function for getting the home data.

```
export async function getHome(id) {
  const { data: homeData, error: homeError } = await supabase
    .from('homes')
    .select('*')
    .eq('id', id)
    .single();

  if (homeError) throw new Error('Could not get home');

  const { user, error: userError } = await supabase.auth.admin.getUserById(
    homeData.user_id,
  );

  if (userError) throw new Error('Could not get user');

  const { fullName, email } = user;

  return { ...homeData, user: { fullName, email } };
}
```

The users table itself is protected and it's impossible to add RLS policies to it. I'm also wondering whether it's a good idea to specify the user's id in this table instead of just email and full name of the user for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Any methods under `supabase.auth.admin` are not allowed to be used from the client side. They are meant to be used from the server side in a secure environment using Supabase's service role key. If you use it with the anon key, you get an error. If you want to get the signed in user from the client side, just use

```js
const {data, error} = await supabase.auth.getSession();
```